# what does objetclass=posixAccount mean in LDAP?

Tags: ldap, jira, openldap

I am trying to take a group from LDAP and integrate it with a group in JIRA.

Can someone explain to me what does objetclass=posixAccount mean in LDAP?
What objectClass and posixAccount mean over here? Is posixAccount something in LDAP?

Thanks,
Tayyab

Answer (score 5):

posixAccount is common objectClass within LDAP used to represent user entries which typically is used for for [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) and Linux/Unix Authentication.